# Why does my submission to a journal remain in review but without an associate editor being assigned?

Tags: journals, paper-submission

My submission to a journal remains in "review" status but no associate editor has been assigned? However, EIA and an editorial assistant have been assigned. Do I need to send an email to the journal to ask?

Comment: Sorry, every journal is different, and we can’t possibly cover every combination of situation X for journal Y. See the above for the general answer.

Comment: It helps if you don't write your question in a form that is full of abbreviations. ... I've edited the question but I'm partly guessing at what the abbreviations mean (I had to look them up)